# Why is this using a table variable?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following existing SQL.  I would like to rewrite this to NOT use the table variable.  But I don't understand this well enough to write a replacement. It seems overly complex to me for just inserting into a table.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrderHeader](@OrderHeader [OrderHeaderTable] READONLY)
AS
BEGIN

declare @FullOrderHeaderTable TABLE ( OrderId int, UpdatedTime DateTime);
INSERT INTO [OrderHeader] 
OUTPUT Inserted.OrderId, Inserted.UpdatedTime INTO @FullOrderHeaderTable
SELECT 
    CustomerId,
    OrderLines,
    OrderStatus,
    NotificationType,
    NotifyEmail,
    NotifySMS,
    PromoCode,
    ReportTotal,
    DiscountAmount,
    OrderTotal,
    GetDate(),
    CreatedBy,
    GetDate(),
    UpdatedBy
FROM @OrderHeader
SELECT OrderId, UpdatedTime FROM @FullOrderHeaderTable;
END
```

Is there a better way to write this without using the table variable?

Greg

Comment: I would use session temp tables (#FullOrderHeaderTable) if the temp db is not overly used and this temp table is not too large

Comment: it is a variable of type `TABLE` to get the inserted data. and the most convenient way of achieving this, why do you think its a complex operation ???

Comment: @sam why do you think that would be any different from a table variable? Timely blog post: http://jasonhall.blogs.sqlsentry.net/2014/01/tempdb-parasites.html

Comment: Because if I need to add a field to the table, it means adding it to the UDTT, and to do that requires dropping the SP that uses it, changing the UDTT, and then recreating it again.  That seems like a lot of work just to add a field.

Comment: Well, what are you then doing with the results of the table variable? This seems to be the most convenient way to collect all of the IDENTITY values generated from a multi-row insert (assuming OrderID is an IDENTITY column).

Comment: You don't need to change the table variable (it's NOT A UDTT!) - it's only collecting the OrderId and the UpdatedTime, not all of the columns in the base table.

Comment: (Edited the question to reflect that this is not a UDTT. Also, where do you get that UDTTs are deprecated? They're not. They're just called alias types. And alias types that are tables are actually more popular than they've ever been, since they're useful for table-valued parameters.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, When searching on the topic, I thought that I read that.

Comment: If you find that reference, please let us know, because it needs to be corrected. You should always verify what you read (or think you read) with an official source. Changing code because you thought you read something was deprecated is very Chicken Little IMHO.

Comment: OK, I just added the first line of the SP that uses the UDTT.  I didn't realize that was necessary to the discussion.

Comment: Ok, now that we know there *is* a table type involved, then yes, your code would need to change to accommodate any changes to the underlying table. But this would happen whether or not you used a table-valued parameter to get this data into the stored procedure - e.g if you called the procedure with individual parameters, one at a time per order, you'd have to change the parameters just like you currently would have to change the alias type.

Comment: @AaronBertrand table variables cannot be updated where as Temp tables can be updated,"if the temp db is not overly used and this temp table is not too large" is just like a disclaimer I mean to use real table if it is too large

Comment: @sam still don't understand. By "updated" do you mean "altered"? If so, what gives you the idea the table variable would need to be altered?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I meant table valued paramter not table variable ,table valued paramter is insert only, I thought he was using table valued parameter defined on table type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you're doing is selecting those columns, then this could be re-written as follows, without a table variable in the first place:

```
INSERT INTO [OrderHeader] 
OUTPUT Inserted.OrderId, Inserted.UpdatedTime
SELECT CustomerId, OrderLines, OrderStatus, ... other columns
FROM @OrderHeader;
```

But let's clear up a couple misconceptions:

1. `DECLARE @x TABLE` is not a UDDT - it is simply a table variable.
2. UDDTs are not deprecated - only the name UDDT (thanks to CLR). These user-defined data types are now officially known as **alias types**.
3. Even if you keep using the table variable approach, it doesn't need to change if the underlying table changes - after all, it is only capturing an ID column and a date. You can add fifty other columns to the table and this code won't break (it will only break if you drop or rename those columns in the `@OrderHeader` table variable, or change the `OrderHeader` table so that the insert fails).

Unrelated: [please get in the habit of specifying the schema when referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: @GregHollywood: Please note that while this is much simpler and will make much more sense in many cases, sometimes an OUTPUT target *must* be specified. In particular, this rewrite will break if/when an INSERT trigger on OrderHeader is introduced. In the words of the [manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx): `If the OUTPUT clause is specified without also specifying the INTO keyword, the target of the DML operation cannot have any enabled trigger defined on it for the given DML action.` (Perhaps whoever wrote the original SP had that in mind when deciding to use INTO)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving inserted data.

**Option One**

Using `OUTPUT clause` with a `Table Variable`  which is the most simplest way. and you are already doing it.

**Option Two**

Using `OUTPUT clause` with a `Temporary Table`, this is the way to go when you are inserting a  lot of data and want to retrieve the inserted data and do some operations on the newly inserted data.

using Temp Tables over Table Variable have one advantage that you can create indexes on them and speed up the operations. Like I mentioned before it is only advised if you are doing some big inserts and dealing with a lot of data.

On the other hand cannot create indexes on the Table Variables.

Comment: * Note, you can create indexes on table variables in SQL Server 2014 (but you still can't benefit from statistics).

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand belated Merry Xmas and Happy New year :) , didnt even know SQL Server 2014 existed. on a side note indexes on temp tables are similar to the indexes on normal table. arnt they ??

Comment: Well, it's still in beta, but this is a well-publicized enhancement. Not sure what you are getting at with your question about indexes.